# Insert variable in validator (PHP)

Tags: php

I got the following validator:

`#[NexusAssert\HasZeroOrXAmountOfCharacters]`

With the following constraint:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
#[Attribute]
class HasZeroOrXAmountOfCharacters extends Constraint
{
    public string $message = 'Wrong number of characters';

    public function validatedBy(): string
    {
        return static::class . 'Validator';
    }

}
```

And the following validator function:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $values = explode(",",$value);
        $count = count($values);


        if ((1 < $count) && ($count < 13) ) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }

    }
```

I would like to give a variable to the NexusAssert like:

`#[NexusAssert\HasZeroOrXAmountOfCharacters(charAmount = 13)]`

And put 'charAmount' in the validate function, instead of a hard coded number. I'd like to know if and how this is possible.